# Who wins at this hand below

Tags: texas-hold-em

If after the river the board shows 7 7 A 10 Q.

Player 1 has Q and 10 in his hand.
Player 2 Has A and 5 in his hand. 
 Who wins?

Answer (score 5):

You didn't specify suits so I'm assuming there aren't any flushes or straight flushes.

Best hand Player 1 can make out of his hand and the board is: A Q Q 10 10, or two pair (Qs and 10s)

Best hand Player 2 can make out of his hand and the board is: A A 7 7 Q, or two pair (Aces and sevens).

Player 2 wins with the higher two pair (Aces beat Queens).